# Lagrangian Mechanics + Account for friction of block

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, friction

$\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}$
I am trying to work out the Lagrangian mechanics for a pendulum problem in order to animate it. I'm working on one of the examples in the Wikipedia page on [Lagrangian mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics) where a pendulum is attached to a block as in the picture below

[image]

I understand how most of this works with the exception of the friction between the block and the surface it resides on.

I've solved the problem with just the Kinetic + Potential energy of the block

$$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} - \frac{\dd}{\dd t}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}\right) = 0;$$
$$  \frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta} - \frac{\dd}{\dd t}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot\theta}\right) = 0;$$

From another example from my class notes of a disk rolling down an inclined plane in 2D the friction can be accounted for by adding a constraint that relates the two generalized coordinates. Do I need to do something similar for friction in this case? How would I do that?

Comment: Google friction, Lagrange, multiplier and you will get answers.

Comment: In the past, I've set the Euler La Grange equation for the x variable equal to the non-conservative forces acting in that direction instead of equal to 0.

Comment: So, @Mephistophales, it should be dL/dx - (d/dt)(dL/dx') = frictionCoefficient * Mg;...?

Comment: Friction coefficient times the NORMAL force

Comment: You will have to do this piecewise, with a friction "potential" term equal to $\pm \mu F_{n} x$, solve the EOM for both signs, and then piece together a solution so that $\dot x$ and $x$ are both continuous at the turnaround points where $\dot x = 0$

Comment: @nhoughto: there's a sign discontiuity.

Comment: @Mephistophales It's "Lagrange" not "La Grange"

Comment: @Mephistophales : It's also Mephistopheles, not Mephistophales!

Comment: @sammy gerbil-the spelling nazis are out in force!

Comment: I would consider adding for static and kinetic friction into the integrals of the Lagrangian for potential energy $ \int F .dx $